# want to remove legend in mpAndroidchart graph

Tags: android, android-layout, graph, mpandroidchart

**want to remove *legend* in mpAndroidchart graph**
[image: want to remove legend in mpAndroidchart graph]

Comment: FYI that "dot" is called as "legend".

Comment: Thanks to inform

Answer (score 2):

Following code is solution for you! 
    BarChart barchart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.mybarchart);

```
barchart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i found it add line

```
               mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```